# Storing double(latitudes) in arraylist changes the value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have retrieved latitudes and longitudes from php and checked whether it has retrieved correctly or not. It has retrieved correctly, say latitudes: 102.11, 101.12, 100.01 and longitudes: 87.01, 101.01, 137.12. Now, I have store it in ArrayList which store LatLng types. When I read the values, longitudes are retrieved as it is, but all the latitudes are retrieved as 90.00. Why is it retrieving so?

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    LatLng loc;
    size=lats.size();//I have tried lngs.size() too, it didn't change the output
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        loc = new LatLng(lats.get(i), lngs.get(i));
        locations.add(loc);
    }
```

I have checked the data in lats arraylist and lngs arraylist, they have the data I have listed above.

Comment: Latitude is restricted to [-90.0,90.0]. Perhaps that is your issue. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#field-summary

Comment: @AvinashReddyPaduri There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the posted code (though I would just do `locations.add(new LatLng(lats.get(i), lngs.get(i));`. Maybe post your `LatLng` code, and/or how you are retrieving the latitudes after they are set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [docs for LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#field-summary). Latitude is restricted to the range `[-90.0,90.0]`. The constructor will clamp the value.

> `latitude`    The point's latitude. This will be clamped to between -90 degrees and +90 degrees inclusive.
>
> `longitude`   The point's longitude. This will be normalized to be within -180 degrees inclusive and +180 degrees exclusive.

Comment: Lol, Thanks. I forgot the basic point. Now, I got it why it is showing like that.